# gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'str' object has no attribute 'get' cleanup policy

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I am trying to run the example command : `gcloud artifacts repositories set-cleanup-policies my-repo --policy=policy.json` mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/artifacts/repositories/set-cleanup-policies) but i am getting the following output :

```
ERROR: gcloud crashed (AttributeError): 'str' object has no attribute 'get'

If you would like to report this issue, please run the following command:
  gcloud feedback

To check gcloud for common problems, please run the following command:
  gcloud info --run-diagnostics
```

I am using the latest version of the CLI as i have downloaded it from [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install-sdk#mac) just now.

Thanks in advance

EDIT :

MY policy is :

```
{
  "name": "keep-latest-version",
  "action": {"type": "Keep"},
  "mostRecentVersions": {
    "packageNamePrefixes": ["users"],
    "keepCount": 1
  }
}
```

Comment: Your policy file doesn't look right. Check https://stackoverflow.com/users/22581048/user22581048's answer again. The policy file contains a list of policies, in your case it should be a list containing a single keep policy.
ofc If you didn't update your answer with the full file, than you should do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your policy.json must be in the following format.

```
[
  {
    "name": "delete-prerelease",
    "action": {"type": "Delete"},
    "condition": {
      "tagState": "tagged",
      "tagPrefixes": ["alpha", "v0"],
      "olderThan": "30d"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but my policy is the same as in the example, let me edit the question

Comment: Sorry i have not looked close enough, it's a list of policy you were right thanks !